# How to get value from key in Jquery (map inside of an array)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var me = [
    {
        "name": "Anon",
        "hobby": "skiing",
        "age": 10
    }]
```

Here's how I'm trying to loop through the array and access every `me[name]`

```
 $.each(me, function(index, value){
        let new_name = $('this').val()['name']
        console.log(new_name)
    });
```

This doesn't work, I've looked all over and I'm very sure there should be a simple way to do what I'm trying to do (without needing to translate things to JSON or write a separate function) Any advice appreciated.

Comment: `$('this')` looks for a DOM elelement like `<this>`.

Comment: You want `value.name` or `this.name`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

I could simply do

```
let new_name = me[index]['name']
```

Thank you @Barmar for pointing me in the right direction